# spacing of \uline

Tags: underline

I use the `\uline` command for underling with break line. But it upper space to the word are small and it seems that it is drawn a line on the words. How can I make some space between line and the word?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `soul` package (or `soulutf8` if you use `utf8 encoding), which has tools to control spacing , thickness and colour of the underline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\setul{0.9ex}{0.8pt}
\setulcolor{IndianRed}

\begin{document}

Once upon a time, a long while ago, there were four little people whose names were \textsc{Violet, Slingsby, Guy} and \textsc{Lionel}
and they all thought they should like to see the world. So they bought a large boat to sail quite round the world by sea, and then they were to come back on the other side by land. The boat was painted blue with green spots, and the sail was yellow with red stripes; and when they set off, they only took a small Cat to steer and look after the boat, besides an \ul{elderly Quangle-Wangle, who had to cook dinner and make the tea}; for which purposes they took a large kettle.

\end{document}
```

[image]